# Continuity of operator.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, limits, continuity

For a fixed given function $f:[0,1]\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is assumed to be measurable and bounded (i.e. $f\in L^\infty([0,T]\times \mathbb{R})$). Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ be open bounded. Define the operator $T:[0,1]\rightarrow L^2(U)$ as
$$T(t)=f(t,\cdot).$$

I would like to know if $T$ is continuous.

I guess one has to prove that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|t-s|<\delta$ then 
$$\|F(t)-F(s)\|_{L^2(U)}<\varepsilon.$$

We have
$$\|F(t)-F(s)\|_{L^2(U)}^2=\int_U |f(t,x)-f(s,x)|^2.$$

Can I say that the latter goes to 0 as $s\to t$? The only assumption I have is that $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ or in particular on $U$. Is this a sufficient assumption? If not, what should one require on $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no chance that this is continuous as long as $f$ is not assumed to be continuous with respect to its first argument.

Comment: Aha! So for instance if $f$ does not depend on $t$ then the operator $T$ is trivially continuous

Comment: Yes, to prove it use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem.